# Side Category for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

My Magento store uses the following code to view categories navigation on the side column:

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php
    function cmpCatPosition($a, $b) {
        if ($a->position == $b->position)
            return 0;
        return ($a->position > $b->position) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    function getChildrenCategoriesHtml($_category){
        $children = explode( ",", $_category->getChildren() );
        //usort($children, 'cmpCatPosition');
        $content = '';
        $content .= '<li class="';
        if(!$children[0])
            $content .= 'has-no-children';
        else
            $content .= 'has-children';
        $content .= '">';
        $content .= '<a href="'.$_category->getUrl().'" ';
        $content .= '>'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
        if($children[0]){
            $content .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus"><i class="icon-plus-squared"></i></a>';
            $content .= '<ul>';
            foreach($children as $child){
                $_subcat = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child );
                $content .= getChildrenCategoriesHtml($_subcat);
            }
            $content .= '</ul>';
        }
        $content .= '</li>';
        return $content;
    }
?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-category-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul class="category-list">
        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <?php
            if($_category->getIsActive()){
                echo getChildrenCategoriesHtml($_category);
            }
            ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".block.block-category-nav .block-title").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("closed")){
                $(".block.block-category-nav .block-content").slideDown();
                $(this).removeClass("closed");
            } else {
                $(".block.block-category-nav .block-content").slideUp();
                $(this).addClass("closed");
            }
        });
        $(".block.block-category-nav .category-list a.plus").click(function(){
            if($(this).parent().hasClass("opened")){
                $(this).parent().children("ul").slideUp();
                $(this).parent().removeClass("opened");
                $(this).children("i.icon-minus-squared").removeClass("icon-minus-squared").addClass("icon-plus-squared");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().children("ul").slideDown();
                $(this).parent().addClass("opened");
                $(this).children("i.icon-plus-squared").removeClass("icon-plus-squared").addClass("icon-minus-squared");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code only show the subcategories of the current category. How should I edit it, so that it would show all categories on every category page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having first line as :

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
```

You can try to replace it with this code :

```
<?php
    $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
?>
```

Comment: It seems to be working, the only problem is that subcategories are show 2 times. Like this (Subcategory1) (Category->Subcategory1)

Comment: @mohammadx90, Updated the code. I forgot about your function `getChildrenCategoriesHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get this work done:

```
<!-- List all categories and their second level subcategories -->
<div class="block block-list block-categories">
    <div id="block-categories" class="block-title active">
        <strong><span>Categories </span></strong>
    </div>
<div id="leftnav" class="block-content" style="display:block">
    <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
            <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></span></a>
                    <?php //if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>
                        <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                        <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                    <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                         <?php $secondLevelSubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                         <?php if (count($secondLevelSubcategories ) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $subcategory->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                <?php foreach($secondLevelSubcategories as $secondLevelSubcategory ): ?>
                                    <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($secondLevelSubcategory )): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($secondLevelSubcategory ) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($secondLevelSubcategory ->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree', 'recursive')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

For further reference, I would like you to visit:

http://iamrookie.com/blog/303/display-all-categories-and-sub-categories-on-left-sidebar-in-magento.html